# Is using COM right for me?

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6, dcom

My work has an application written in VB6. I am tasked with writing another, different, application in C# .NET. I am not allowed to change the VB6 code, but I need to call a function (from my .NET application) every time a particular function gets called in the VB6 application.

My boss recommended using COM or DCOM for this task. I am not familiar with either of these topics, and am having trouble finding a tutorial that I can understand easily and that relates to my task.

Can I do this using COM or will I have to modify the existing VB6 code?

Comment: It's not clear. The road is: VB6 calls C# that calls something OR C# calls VB6 OR something else... And the "I need to call a function"... Which language is it?

Comment: Unless the VB6 code is already a com object aka componet, i think you are going to have to modify in some way. Either exposing it as a com oject, of have it call .Net code exposed as a com object.

Comment: For simplicity you could use DDE if both apps runs on the same machine, a bit outdated approach, but very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose the function in VB6 as COM (ActiveX DLL). This is straight forward. 
http://vb-helper.com/howto_activex_dll.html

Calling a COM Object is easy too. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp12022005231615PM/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a VB6 application whose source code should not be changed.  Now every time a method in the VB6 application is called you also want to call a method in another component (C#).

The above is an assumption since your question is not 100% clear.

If that is the case and you can't change the VB6 application then you *might* be able to do something using [COM Channel Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/deleg.aspx) (assuming the VB6 app is composed of COM objects).

But that would be using C++ and low level COM which is probably something you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** you are asking about invoking a method from your C# **application** from within your VB6 **application**.  So we are talking about some form of inter-process communication (hence the comment about DCOM).

I've used .NET Remoting to replace DCOM in some applications by creating a COM-callable .NET library to act as the client with the remoting objects being hosted in a .NET application.  Your VB6 application uses the objects, and the methods execute on the server.

**BUT** you will have to modify your VB6 application, at least a little, to inject the new calls to your .NET.  Can you be more clear on the requirements to not change the VB6 application?